# Python Input Read Formatting

Tags: python, input, format

How can i read two values typed in one line to two variable by python
like %d %d in c
raw_input reads everything in that line

eg 1 0

i want 1 in x and 0 in y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using larsmans' method is good enough. If you **really** want the scanf thing, and most importly, don't want to read the **whole line**. Try this, it may be slow, though.

```
import re
import sys

class Pin:
    formatDict = {'%d': r'(\d+)', '%f': r'(\d+\.?\d*)'}
    def __init__(self, input=sys.stdin):
        self.input = input

    def scanf(self, format):
        # change the C style format to python regex
        for a, b in self.formatDict.iteritems():
            format = format.replace(a, b)
        patt = re.compile('^\\s*%s$'%format, re.M)
        buf = ''
        matched = 0
        while 1:
            c = self.input.read(1)
            if not c: break
            buf += c
            g = patt.match(buf)
            if g:
                # matched, but there may be more to match, so don't break now
                matched = 1
                matchedGroup = g
            elif matched:
                # the first unmatch after a match, seek back one char and break now
                self.input.seek(-1, 1)
                break
        if matched:
            return tuple(eval(x) for x in matchedGroup.groups())

scanf = Pin(open('in', 'r')).scanf
print scanf('%d %d')
print scanf('%f %f')
```

Ugly but interesting, right?

Answer (score 5):

```
x, y = map(int, raw_input().split())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the whole line and use regular expression to parse it. Use groups to get the parts that are interesting for you. Otherwise just use string.split if you don't need such a control.